# React Material Table, First and Last Page Button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In a MUI React Table, how do I add First and Last page button? This only has previous and next page button. I want a First and Last Page double arrow icon, or something out of the box.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mui v5 `<TablePagination/>` has props called `showFirstButton` and `showLastButton`. See more https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-pagination/